# Javascript: DIV content to URL String, Result = [Object Node List] and 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, wordpress, undefined, innerhtml, nodelist

This is a very specific question, so sorry if it sounds repetitive.

I have a block of code that manipulates a Wordpress's "Press This" feature that allows for quick blogging about a remote site, including copying a selection of text.

What I'm wanting to manipulate it to, is to re-blog (with credit) an entire blog post from a wordpress engine site. Wordpress.com has this feature built into their site, but if you have your own hosted site, this feature isn't present.

I have managed to select the correct DIV, along with getting the pop-up to work, however the content isn't there.

The results from :

```
 y = d.getElementsByClassName('entry'),
```

is that y = [Object Node List]

```
z = y.innerHTML,
```

the result is 'undefined'

```
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i) {
z = z + y[i];}
```

the result is '[object HTMLDivElement][object HTMLDivElement]'
(The result is the same as if it pulls from y.innerHTML)

I've searched extensively for help, yet can not introduce a solution to the code.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you put a ',' at the end where a ';' should be

```
 y = d.getElementsByClassName('entry'),
```

Your problem is that getElement **s** ByClassName('entry') returns an array of **all** elements which share the class name 'entry';

If you want to access the first you should use

```
y = d.getElementsByClassName('entry')[0];
```

Or you can use **for** to go through all:

```
for(var i in d.getElementsByClassName('entry')) {
  y = d.getElementsByClassName('entry')[i];
  alert(y.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: So far So good. Thanks @AmShaegar ! 

The HTML gets put into line just fine for that, it's just not the php interpreting it, which it isn't doing so now as there's HTML tags, it's getting confused. Thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, try this:

```
var z = '';
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i) {
   z = z + y[i].innerHTML;
}
alert(z); //will alert the html content of all your .entry elements
```

Comment: @user1823414 you should clarify more what is not working for you, or post the full code..

Comment: I need to basically turn the contents of the DIV into a string so it can put into the URL, so that the Wordpress php knows what to do with it. That's only parameters I've got to work with, otherwise it'll mean making a wordpress plugin which I don't want to do.

Comment: @user1823414 The problem is you didn't copy my code accordingly, I have `y[i].innerHTML;` where you have `y[i].innerhtml;` . The casing matters.